# running dev_appserver.py from linux terminal

Tags: python, linux, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I have recently spun up a VM on Google Compute Engine with the view of creating a development environment in the cloud.

I have the source code and install the Google Cloud SDK and the App-Engine SDK. However when i try to run `dev_appserver.py` I get the following error, even after ensuring firewall rules are created.

```
x@dev:~/code$ dev_appserver.py --host dev.cfcmelbourne.org --port=8080 cfc/
    INFO     2015-05-20 12:54:22,744 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
    INFO     2015-05-20 12:54:23,280 sdk_update_checker.py:273] This SDK release is newer than the advertised release.
    INFO     2015-05-20 12:54:23,361 api_server.py:190] Starting API server at: http://localhost:38624
    INFO     2015-05-20 12:54:23,441 api_server.py:615] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
    INFO     2015-05-20 12:54:23,441 api_server.py:618] Saving search indexes
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/xxx/software/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 83, in <module>
        _run_file(__file__, globals())
      File "/home/xxx/software/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
        execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
      File "/home/xxx/software/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1002, in <module>
        main()
      File "/home/xxx/software/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 995, in main
        dev_server.start(options)
      File "/home/xxx/software/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 798, in start
        self._dispatcher.start(options.api_host, apis.port, request_data)
      File "/home/xxx/software/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 189, in start
        _module.start()
      File "/home/xxx/software/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1174, in start
        self._balanced_module.start()
      File "/home/xxx/software/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 315, in start
        self._start_all_fixed_port(host_ports)
      File "/home/xxx/software/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 352, in _start_all_fixed_port
        raise BindError('Unable to bind %s:%s' % self.bind_addr)
    google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind dev.cfcmelbourne.org:8080
    xxx@dev:~/code$
```

The firewall rules clear allow 8080 TCP access.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with firewalls. It's not letting you bind to port 8080, probably because something else is already bound to that port.

Answer (score 0):

run netstat -tulpn as root user to see if their is a process running on port 8080 . type fuser 8080/tcp to get PID of process running on port 8080 and kill that port or simply use argument -k with fuser command i.e fuser -k 8080/tcp to kill that process. it work fine for me.